# How to output on browser nusoap_client vars

Tags: php, nusoap

I am fancing an issue with nusoap.php directly with php errors found`DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input` but firstly I would like to know how to get output of var of code at browser:

```
...require_once("nusoap.php");


$wsdl = $ilias_base_url."/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl"; 
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);

$error  = $client->getError();

$par = array(
        "client" => $ilias_client,
        "username" => $ilias_soap_username,
        "password" => $ilias_soap_user_password,
);

$ret = $client->call('login', $par);

echo $ret;...
```

I just want to see at my web browser window var `$ret`.
Many thanks for all help. 
FYI:

```
php --version
PHP 5.5.14 (cli)
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Oh right resolved. I forgot to check it system have installed required packages:

```
php5-pear-SOAP
php5-soap
```